# Regex for ClassName.PropertyName

Tags: c#, regex

I don't know `Regex`,

But I need to have *regex expression* for evaluation of `ClassName.PropertyName`?

Need to validate some values from appSettings for being compliant with `ClassName.PropertyName` convention

**"ClassName.PropertyName"** - this is the only format that is valid, the rest below is invalid:

```
"Personnel.FirstName1"   <- the only string that should match
"2Personnel.FirstName1"
"Personnel.33FirstName"
"Personnel..FirstName"
"Personnel.;FirstName"
"Personnel.FirstName."
"Personnel.FirstName   "
" Personnel.FirstName"
" Personnel. FirstName"
" 23Personnel.3FirstName"
```

I have tried this (from the link posted as *duplicate*):

```
 ^\w+(.\w+)*$
```

but it doesn't work: I have *false positives*, e.g. `2Personnel.FirstName1` as well as `Personnel.33FirstName` *passes the check* when both should have been *rejected*.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very specific - but I think you need to escape the dot character in your pattern.

Comment: Why not use `^[a-z]{1}\w+\.[a-z]{1}\w+$`? Or is the property name optional?

Comment: you forgot to escape `.` to `\.`, `.` matches any character

Comment: It should be either `^\w+(?:\.\w+)*$` or `^\w+\.\w+$` depending on what you need. Or even `\A\w+(?:\.\w+)*\z`

Comment: Also, `\w`includes numbers, which is not a valid first character for a C# identifier.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*$`

Comment: pritaeas, you expression doesnt work: https://regexr.com/?32gk0

Comment: Post a [mcve] with testcases.

Comment: Expression ^\w+(?:\.\w+)*$ almost works, but it still makes 2Class.Method1 a valid string, classname cannot start with number, as well as PropertyName

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, it is not a duplicate, check yourself before posting

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, thank you, looks like your regex is working! ^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*$    Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start from single identifier:

1. Its *first* character must be letter or underscope
2. It can *contain* letters, underscopes and digits

So the regular expression for an identifier is

```
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*
```

Next, we should chain identifier with `.` (do not forget to escape `.`) an indentifier followed by zero or more `.` + identifier:

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?:\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*$
```

In case it must be **exactly two** identifiers (and not, say `abc.def.hi` - three ones)

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

Tests:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "Personnel.FirstName1",  // the only string that should be matched
  "2Personnel.FirstName1",
  "Personnel.33FirstName",
  "Personnel..FirstName",
  "Personnel.;FirstName",
  "Personnel.FirstName.",
  "Personnel.FirstName   ",
  " Personnel.FirstName",
  " Personnel. FirstName",
  " 23Personnel.3FirstName",
} ;

string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*$";

var results = tests
  .Select(test => 
    $"{"\"" + test + "\"",-25} : {(Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern) ? "matched" : "failed")}"");

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
```

Outcome:

```
"Personnel.FirstName1"    : matched
"2Personnel.FirstName1"   : failed
"Personnel.33FirstName"   : failed
"Personnel..FirstName"    : failed
"Personnel.;FirstName"    : failed
"Personnel.FirstName."    : failed
"Personnel.FirstName   "  : failed
" Personnel.FirstName"    : failed
" Personnel. FirstName"   : failed
" 23Personnel.3FirstName" : failed
```

**Edit**: In case *culture specific* names (like `äöü.FirstName`) should be accepted (see Rand Random's comments) then `[A-Za-z]` range should be changed into `\p{L}` - *any letter*. Exotic possibility - culture specific *digits* (e.g. Persian ones - `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`) can be solved by changing `0-9` into `\d`

```
// culture specific letters, but not digits 
string pattern = @"^[\p{L}_][\p{L}0-9_]*(?:\.[\p{L}_][\p{L}0-9_]*)*$";
```

If each identifier should not *exceed sertain length* (say, `16`) we should redesign initial identifier pattern: mandatory letter or underscope followed by `[0..16-1] == {0,15}` letters, digits or underscopes

```
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]{0,15}
```

And we have

```
string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]{0,15}(?:\.[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]{0,15})*$";
```

Comment: Another thing, was just playing around. It also fails to validate length `Name 'superlongclassname' exceeds the maximum length allowed in metadata.`

Comment: Was to fast on the delete comment button, only read "In case culture specific…" and deleted my comment - only saw later that you mentioned my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]*[0-9]$
```

or

```
^[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]*[0-9]+$
```

if you need more than one numerical character in the number suffix